# 481 Call Leg/Transaction Does Not Exist using SipUnit

Tags: sip, voip

I've changed from SIPr to SipUnit, and I'm trying to make a basic call. The server has digest authentication. Unfurnately, I keep getting a "481 Call Leg/Transaction Does Not Exist" and I'm sure it is because of a pretty obvious reason, but I can't seem to solve it... I've tried everything. Here is the critical piece from the PBX's logs. Thanks in advance, if someone can explain to me why this is happening!

```
- --> SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
-     From: <sip:6000@auto>;tag=126319630
-     To: <sip:6001@auto>;tag=2ff812a8-da5512ac-1b94-6006-5a9c94-45273d5a-5a9c94
-     Call-ID: e0114805d5e2e318089ce3ef710aad63@10.200.10.59
-     CSeq: 1 INVITE
-     Contact: <sip:6001@172.18.85.218:1060>
-     Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="radvision.com",nonce="c0cf196770955ca0fc6e3e65dc0cdb410000000055c1cef4",algorithm=MD5
-     Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.10.59:9001;received=172.18.85.218;rport=1060;branch=z9hG4bK-373136-f42a6651eba8e1583353591126fdf561
-     Content-Length: 0



- <-- ACK sip:6001@auto SIP/2.0
-     Call-ID: e0114805d5e2e318089ce3ef710aad63@10.200.10.59
-     Max-Forwards: 70
-     From: <sip:6000@auto>;tag=126319630
-     To: <sip:6001@auto>;tag=2ff812a8-da5512ac-1b94-6006-5a9c94-45273d5a-5a9c94
    -     Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.10.59:9001;branch=z9hG4bK-373136-f42a6651eba8e1583353591126fdf561
-     CSeq: 1 ACK
-     Route: <sip:172.18.85.218:1060;lr;transport=udp>
-     Content-Length: 0



- <-- INVITE sip:6001@auto SIP/2.0
-     Call-ID: e0114805d5e2e318089ce3ef710aad63@10.200.10.59
-     CSeq: 2 INVITE
-     From: <sip:6000@auto>;tag=126319630
-     To: <sip:6001@auto>;tag=2ff812a8-da5512ac-1b94-6006-5a9c94-45273d5a-5a9c94
-     Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.10.59:9001;branch=z9hG4bK-373136-a29ab2f2fc28a3f00e2cd290bac58473
-     Max-Forwards: 70
-     Contact: <sip:6000@10.200.10.59:9001;transport=udp;lr>
-     Route: <sip:172.18.85.218:1060;lr;transport=udp>,<sip:172.18.85.218:1060;lr;transport=udp>
-     Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="6000",realm="radvision.com",nonce="c0cf196770955ca0fc6e3e65dc0cdb410000000055c1cef4",uri="sip:6001@auto",response="79af22055592634e57d5c17e59da166e",algorithm=MD5
-     Content-Length: 0



- --> SIP/2.0 481 Call Leg/Transaction Does Not Exist
-     From: <sip:6000@auto>;tag=126319630
-     To: <sip:6001@auto>;tag=2ff812a8-da5512ac-1b94-6006-5a9c94-45273d5a-5a9c94
-     Call-ID: e0114805d5e2e318089ce3ef710aad63@10.200.10.59
-     CSeq: 2 INVITE
-     Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.10.59:9001;branch=z9hG4bK-373136-a29ab2f2fc28a3f00e2cd290bac58473
-     Content-Length: 0
```

I'm using code similar to the example TestWithProxyAuthentication.java.

Answer (score 1):

In that flow you attached, registration was not completed.
After receiving "407 Proxy Authentication Required", You should send 2nd REGISTER with Proxy-Authorization header.